# Java - Point on line

Tags: java, line, point

How can i find out if a Point(x,y) is on a the Line created between two other Points?
I tried this but something seems to be wrong, as i don't get the results i should.

```
public boolean intersects(Point k, Point z, Point p) {

        Line2D line = new Line2D.Float(k.x, k.y, z.x, z.y);

        if (line.ptLineDist(p) == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: For the record, your entire `if` statement is extraneous. You can just `return line.ptLineDist(p) == 0;`.

Comment: Won't you need to use a delta of some sorts, since this is floating point numbers you're dealing with? It will be rare that you will encounter equality with floating point numbers that are digitally represented, and so your calculation will need to solve for "close enough to the line to be considered on it" not for "on the line".

Comment: I believe @HovercraftFullOfEels has the answer.  You should print the value of `line.ptLineDist(p)` -- it should be a very small number.  If not, then the given point is not on the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, taking Hovercraft's note about floating point numbers' imprecision into account.

```
public boolean intersects(Point k, Point z, Point p) {
       return new Line2D.Float(k, z).ptLineDist(p) <= 0.01;
}
```

Comment: I've also completely forgotten; is it legal to write `return new Line2D.Float(k, z).contains(p);`?

Comment: Aha, fantastic, I thought as much. Code shortened.

Comment: Removed the `contains()` method. The API says it always returns `false` because a line has no area.