# How to click a Polygon border and add this point to polygon

Tags: java, graphics, awt, polygon, graphics2d

this is my first question in Stackoverflow.
I'm creating an IDE for adventure games in JAVA, and i need to set the walkable area. This shape is a polygon which i can paint with his vertex already, and i can to add new points. The problem is that i can't to detect if mouse position is Only over the polygon's border. This is for create new vertex without deform the shape.

Does exist any way to select the border/stroke of a polygon and register this event out of the PaintComponent ?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can iterate over the polygon's point and determine if you hit a line.

```
Polygon p; //your polygon
int x_mouse;//your mouse click pos
int y_mouse;
for (int i = 0; i < p.npoints; i ++){
    int x_from = 0;
    int y_from = 0;         
    int x_to = 0;
    int y_to = 0;

    if (i == 0){ //i-1 == -1 -> p.npoints-1
        x_from = p.xpoints[p.npoints-1];
        y_from = p.ypoints[p.npoints-1];
    }else{
        x_from = p.xpoints[i-1];
        y_from = p.ypoints[i-1];
    }       
    x_to = p.xpoints[i];
    y_to = p.ypoints[i];


    Line2D line = new Line2D.Double(x_from, y_from, x_to, y_to);
    if (line.ptLineDist(new Point(x_mouse, y_mouse)) <= 0.01){
        //you hit
    }

}
```

have a look at [Java - Point on line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986346/java-point-on-line) to see why  'ptLineDist(p) < 0.01' should be preferred.

Comment: It works!. Now i only need to implement a method to sort the polygon's vertexs for not deforming it, i will do it myself. But the click event in the polygon's border works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: the polygon points are kindof sorted, already.... the order is order how it is drawn. if you want to sort the points around a center (mayb clockwise or counterclockwise) you can use `Math.atan2(double theta)` (see also http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13229/sorting-array-of-points-in-clockwise-order)

Answer (score 0):

In order to know if the user clicked a point along the border of your painted polygon, you'll need to calculate the distance between the clicked point and each line segment. Search for "[point to line distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line)".

Since the edge technically is infinitely thin (it occupies no area), you'll need to test if the point is within some small threshold distance of the edge.

Comment: At first, thanks for your help. The problem it's how to register that distance with a mouse event too. There are some methods like "distance()" Example: mouseEvent.getPoint().distance(point) to calculate it, but i would need too the stroke width of the shape to click it and work with it